# Stop Eclipse from sliding curly braces way to the right for methods returning generic types

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, formatter, curly-braces

I configured Eclipse to adhere to my employer's code style, but one tiny detail isn't working right: I told it to put all braces on the next line, unindented, and line wrap method parameters, aligning on columns. The preview window shows me the behavior I want:

```
void foo(int arg1, int arg2,
       int arg3, int arg4,
       int arg5, int arg6)
{
  // method body
}
```

This works for non-generic return types in my code as well.
However, when I declare a method with a generic return type, Eclipse slides the curly braces over to the first argument column:

```
ArrayList<String> foo(int arg1, int arg2,
       int arg3, int arg4,
       int arg5, int arg6)
       {
  // method body
       }
```

Am I missing some configuration option or should I file a bug report?

EDIT: I'm running Eclipse Juno, Build ID 20130225-0426 on OS X 10.8.3

Comment: Please fill a bug report and post it as an answer when you get some feedback. Formatting of generics and wrapped lines sucks in eclipse. In fact there is already an issue open : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384959 - maybe ask there ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've gone through a few bug reports myself and the general impression I got was that Eclipse's Java Formatter is fundamentally broken in some subtle ways - for one, it hasn't been properly updated since Generics were introduced to Java. There's another bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303519) from a Google engineer who offered his patches, but I don't think anything ever came from it. This seems to be a known and (for now) tolerated issue...